# how to sort the result of multiquery?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I use `mysqli_multi_query()` function and get result of two query in such a way that all first query result is sort date wise first and second query after that.

Here is my queries:

```
$query = "SELECT 
            `b`.`class_name`, 
            `c`.`main_code`,`c`.`account_title`, 
            `a`.`ledger_entry`, `a`.`balance` AS `debit`, `a`.`date`, `a`.`v.no`, `a`.`interactive_person` 
         FROM `vouchers` AS `a`,`classes` AS `b`, `data` AS `c` 
         WHERE `a`.`post_status`='yes' 
           AND `a`.`cancel_status`='off' 
           AND `a`.`type`='CP' 
           AND `a`.`class_id` = `b`.`class_id` 
           AND `a`.`account_id`=`c`.`account_code` 
           AND `a`.`date` BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate';";
$query .= "SELECT 
             `b`.`class_name`, 
             `c`.`main_code`,`c`.`account_title`, 
             `a`.`ledger_entry`, sum(`a`.`balance`) AS `credit`, `a`.`date`, `a`.`v.no`, `a`.`interactive_person` 
           FROM `vouchers` AS `a`,`classes` AS `b`,`data` AS `c` 
           WHERE `a`.`post_status`='yes' 
             AND `a`.`cancel_status`='off' 
             AND `a`.`type`='CP' 
             AND `a`.`class_id` = `b`.`class_id` 
             AND `a`.`interactive_person`=`c`.`main_code` 
             AND `a`.`date` BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate' GROUP BY `v.no`;";
```

These are two query and now let me show you the way I use multiquery function:

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $query)) {
    do {
        // Store first result set
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($con)) {
            // Fetch one and one row
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                if ($y > 700) {
                    $y = 30;
                    $pdf->AddPage();
                    $x = 36;
                }
                $y = $y + 18;
                $x = 10;

                $debit = 0;
                $credit = $row['credit'];
                if($credit==""){$credit = 0;}
                $debit = $row['debit'];
                if($debit==""){$debit = 0;}

                $pdf->SetFont('Times', 'B', 12, '', true);
                $pdf->MultiCell(70, 18, $row['date'], 1, 'L', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
                $x = $x + 70;
                $pdf->SetFont('Times', '', 12, '', true);
                $pdf->MultiCell(50, 18, $row['v.no'], 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
                $x = $x + 50;
                $pdf->MultiCell(100, 18, $row['main_code'], 1, 'L', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
                $x = $x + 70;
                $pdf->MultiCell(100, 18, $row['account_title'], 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
                $x = $x + 100;
                $pdf->MultiCell(100, 18, $row['class_name'], 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
                $x = $x + 100;
                $pdf->MultiCell(120, 18,$credit , 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
                $x = $x + 120;
                $pdf->MultiCell(80, 18, $debit , 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);

            }
            // Free result set
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($con));
}
```

Everything work perfectly and I get output in pdf as:

[image]

So now what I want to do is sort the details I got **order by "ref number" or "date"**.

How can I do it ? Can I do it with any php function ? or should I change the technique of fetching data from database ?

Comment: Please try to simplify your query as it is difficult to read.

Comment: nothing special in query. if i had problem in the query i would simplify it. ignore the query but see that result in pdf and then give me suggest me what i need to do with php code?

Comment: You can use php sort function for it.

Comment: @Devrajverma for example ? can you name it ? i couldn't find it

Comment: @ArsalanAfridi kindly refer this http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php link i hope you will get proper solution as you asset

Comment: You can do a union of these , select the columns and use order by. Then no need to iterate in your code, execute one sql and get the return

Comment: @VinuBibin in union the column in both query should be same and where clause should be same for both query but here i connect two table in both query in two different ways and also the number of columns are not same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after execution of query storing data in array and then sorted it and it work the way i want so the answer is

```
$pdf->SetFont('Times', 'B', 12, '', true);

$y = $y + 20;
$pdf->MultiCell(200, 18, 'Cash Payment Vouchers', 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
$y = $y + 20;
$pdf->MultiCell(70, 18, 'Date', 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
$x = $x + 70;
$pdf->MultiCell(50, 18, 'Ref.No', 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
$x = $x + 50;
$pdf->MultiCell(70, 18, 'Code', 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
$x = $x + 70;
$pdf->MultiCell(100, 18, 'Account Title', 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
$x = $x + 100;
$pdf->MultiCell(100, 18, 'Class', 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
$x = $x + 100;
$pdf->MultiCell(120, 18, 'Credit', 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
$x = $x + 120;
$pdf->MultiCell(80, 18, 'Debit', 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $query)) {
    do {
        // Store first result set
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($con)) {
            // Fetch one and one row

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $a[] = $row;
                $vNo[] = $row['date'];

                array_multisort($a, SORT_ASC, $vNo);
            }
            // Free result set
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($con));
    array_multisort($a, SORT_ASC, $vNo);
    foreach ($a as $ro) {
        if ($y > 700) {
        $y = 30;
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $x = 10;
    }
        $debit = 0;
        $credit = $ro['credit'];
        if ($credit == "") {
            $credit = 0;
        }
        $debit = $ro['debit'];
        if ($debit == "") {
            $debit = 0;
        }
        $y = $y + 18;
        $x = 10;
        $pdf->SetFont('Times', 'B', 12, '', true);
        $pdf->MultiCell(70, 18, $ro['date'], 1, 'L', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
        $x = $x + 70;
        $pdf->SetFont('Times', '', 12, '', true);
        $pdf->MultiCell(50, 18, $ro['v.no'], 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
        $x = $x + 50;
        $pdf->MultiCell(100, 18, $ro['main_code'], 1, 'L', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
        $x = $x + 70;
        $pdf->MultiCell(100, 18, $ro['account_title'], 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
        $x = $x + 100;
        $pdf->MultiCell(100, 18, $ro['class_name'], 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
        $x = $x + 100;
        $pdf->MultiCell(120, 18, $credit, 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
        $x = $x + 120;
        $pdf->MultiCell(80, 18, $debit, 1, 'C', true, 1, $x, $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
        $sum += $credit;
    }
}
$y = $y + 20;
$pdf->MultiCell(390, 18, 'Total :', 1, 'R', true, 1, '10', $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
$pdf->MultiCell(120, 18, $sum, 1, 'C', true, 1, '400', $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
$pdf->MultiCell(80, 18, $sum, 1, 'C', true, 1, '520', $y, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
unset($a);
unset($vNo);
$sum = 0;
```

}

main code to solve my problem was

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $query)) {
    do {
        // Store first result set
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($con)) {
            // Fetch one and one row

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $a[] = $row;
                $vNo[] = $row['date'];

                array_multisort($a, SORT_ASC, $vNo);
            }
            // Free result set
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($con));
```

and then use foreach loop to get data from stored array named $a

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query statements.
Just append "ORDER BY `ref_number` ASC" at the end of each SQL query for example.

ASC stands for ascending (small to big), DESC for descending (big to small)

Comment: ahahah its already order by date. in short you need to understand my question before answer ! if its so simple i would never ask question here but its a bit complex and you need to see the result i uploaded and then try to help me with a php code

Comment: let me explain it: i use two query (multiquery) it execute the first query and sort it date wise or ref number then it execute the second query and sort it after the exsisting values. like 1,2,3 then second query data makes it format 1,2,3,1,2,3. i want a code which execute both query then sort it then give me output 1,1,2,2,3,3

Answer (score 0):

Sort directly the array

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    foreach ($row as $r) {
        $dates[] = $r['date'];
    }

    array_multisort($row, SORT_ASC, $dates);

......

}
```